# Finding solution to matrix equation over GF(2) with minimal true variables

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, boolean-algebra

I am looking for a general way to find a solution to a system of equations in GF(2) such that the solution has the least amount of true variables. After Gaussian elimination I get a matrix like such:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccccccccc|c}1&0&0&0&1&1&1&0&0&1\\
0&1&0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1\\
0&0&1&0&0&1&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Finding a solution is trivial. If the variables are named $a$, $b$, ..., then $\{a, b, d\} = 1$ is a valid solution. However, $\{e\} = 1$ is also a valid solution, and only uses a single true variable.

In this example we got 'lucky' because it's easy to spot the minimal solution, but this obviously doesn't generalize. Is there a fast general method to find a solution that minimizes the number of true variables?

Comment: Sorry, but I know little of complexity theory, so I can't answer your comment. I had left my answer up for a while hoping I could fix it. But I'm coming  up blank right now, so I am deleting it in hopes that this will encourage replies from those more knowledgable in this field.

Comment: This question is equivalent to [this question on theoretical computer science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10396/0-1-vector-xor-problem). [It is NP-complete through a reduction to the minimal-weight code problem.](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/10402/6482)